# How To InvalidateRect With GDIPlus

Tags: delphi, gdi+

All of the GDIPlus demo code I can find draws without invalidation.  So how do you invalidate a rectangle in GDIPlus API when drawing with MouseMove with TImage on a TScrollbox?

```
function NormalizeRect ( R: TRect ): TRect;
begin

  // This routine normalizes a rectangle. It makes sure that the Left,Top
  // coords are always above and to the left of the Bottom,Right coords.

  with R do
  begin

    if Left > Right then
      if Top > Bottom then
        Result := Rect ( Right, Bottom, Left, Top )
      else
        Result := Rect ( Right, Top, Left, Bottom )
    else if Top > Bottom then
      Result := Rect ( Left, Bottom, Right, Top )
    else
      Result := Rect ( Left, Top, Right, Bottom );

  end;

end;

procedure TFormMain.Image1MouseDown ( Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer );
begin
  if Line1.Down then
  begin
    GPPointStart := MakePoint ( X, Y );
  end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.Image1MouseMove ( Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer );
var
  graphics: TGPGraphics;
  pen: TGPPen;
  SolidBrush: TGPSolidBrush;
  rgbTriple: windows.RGBTRIPLE;
  iRect: TRect;
begin  
  if Line1.Down then
  begin
    if ssLeft in Shift then
    begin
      iRect := NormalizeRect ( Rect ( X, Y, Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Width, Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Height ) );
      InvalidateRect ( ScrollBox1.Handle, @iRect, TRUE );
      graphics := TGPGraphics.Create ( Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle );
      graphics.Flush ( FlushIntentionFlush );
      GPPointEnd := MakePoint ( X, Y );
      rgbTriple := ColorToRGBTriple ( ColorBox1.Selected );
      pen := TGPPen.Create ( MakeColor ( StrToInt ( Alpha1.Text ), rgbTriple.rgbtRed, rgbTriple.rgbtGreen, rgbTriple.rgbtBlue )
        );
      pen.SetWidth ( StrToInt ( Size1.Text ) );
      graphics.DrawLine ( pen, GPPointStart.X, GPPointStart.Y, GPPointEnd.X, GPPointEnd.Y );
      graphics.Free;
      Image1.Refresh;
    end;
   end;
end;
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Using GDIPlus Library from http://www.progdigy.com with Delphi 2010.

Answer (score 6):

The `InvalidateRect` command has nothing to do with GDI+. It's a command that tells the OS that a certain portion of a *window* is invalid and should be repainted. When the OS next decides to repaint that window, the program can ask the OS how much of the window needs painting.

Your code is calling `InvalidateRect`, and then it's painting over that same portion of the window. The window is still invalidated, though, so the OS will ask your program to repaint that area later, when you next process a `wm_Paint` message.

I don't know why you would expect your image to look any different, and it has nothing to do with invalidating the scroll box. It looks like you clicked on the character's eye, and the dragged the mouse down and the the right, clockwise.

At each mouse movement, you draw a new line from the original pint to the current mouse position. You draw the line directly on the currently displayed bitmap, and then you ask the image control to redraw itself. It obeys and draws the bitmap — that bitmap that you just added another line to.

I suspect what you *intended* to happen was for each mouse movement to result in *one* black line to appear over an otherwise unsullied image. `InvalidateRect` won't help with that. You need to redraw the original image over the previous line position, and the draw the new line. `InvalidateRect` does not help you "undo" a previous graphic operation. It just  tells the OS that a certain portion of a window should be repainted sometime. It doesn't say what colors those invalidated pixels should be repainted *with*. That's what `wm_Paint` is for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I understand what you are telling me, but I still don't know how to fix it.  Any more advise?

Comment: Instead of drawing to the bitmap, draw to the scroll box. That leaves the bitmap untouched. Invalidate the old line area. Refresh to make the image paint over the old line. Then draw the new line. If you need more help, ask a new question about what you're really trying to do.

Comment: @Rob, *instead of drawing to the bitmap, draw to the scroll box*, the `TScrollBox` has no canvas where you can paint to. And it wouldn't even be a good idea when you consider the content scrolling. I guess you meant *instead of drawing to the image, draw to the bitmap* don't you ?

Comment: No, @Tlama. Drawing to the bitmap is part of what led to this problem in the first place. Drawing to the image control might work. The bottom line is that you need to draw to an *impermanent surface*. The bitmap doesn't qualify since it remembers what you drew.

Comment: @TLama - It's the opposite of drawing outside a paint handler and then wondering where might have the drawing been gone after the next paint cylce. Bill wants that behavior, but since he modifies the bitmap the drawing persists.